# is this Laravel Relationship error undefined variable $task

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing project management app in Laravel 5.2. in My application I have one project many tasks and one task have many file attachments. this is My file attachment view file

```
@foreach($task->files as $file) //line 14
                <div>
                    <div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                        <span>

                            <a href="{{ $file->file_url }}" target="_blank">{{ $file->file_name }}</a>

                   </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and My FileController is this

```
use Cloudder;
use App\File as File;
use App\Task;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class FilesController extends Controller
{
public function uploadAttachments(Request $request,$id,$taskId)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'file_name'     => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,pdf|between:1,7000',
        ]);

        $filename     = $request->file('file_name')->getRealPath();

        Cloudder::upload($filename, null);
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

$fileUrl = Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId(), ["width" => $width, "height" => $height]);
        $this->saveUploads($request, $fileUrl, $id,$taskId);
```

and route is this

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}/', [
     'uses' => 'FilesController@uploadAttachments',
     'as'   => 'projects.files',
     'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

but got this error

```
ErrorException in ae0a86ab95cb7f092eb44a17fd000e94f21b305d.php line 14:
Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\13\Desktop\acxian\resources\views\files\form.blade.php)
```

how can fix this problem?

**file Model**

```
use Auth;
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class File extends Model
{
    public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }

    public function scopeTask($query, $taskId)
    {
        return $query->where('task_id', $taskId);
    }

    public function task(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Comment: and where is the method that displays the view? the one that actually matters since the error is in a view

Comment: ok this is my view **public function show($project_id,$task_id)
 {
    $project = Project::find($project_id);
    $task = Task::find($task_id);
  
return view('tasks.show')->withProject($project)->withTask($task);
   
 }**

Comment: like lagbox said, pls show the return of the MyFileController. something like: return view('mytaskview', ['task' => $somevar]);

Comment: return **return redirect()->back($task)->with('info', 'Your Attachment has been uploaded Successfully');
    }**

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the $task collection to your blade view as shown below

```
$task = Task::all() //collect task collection as per your logic
return view('files.form', compact('task'));
```

Comment: where should I put this code? in My Controller methods

Comment: in function from which you load your view

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass $task data to your view (blade file) like this

```
return view('files.form', $task);
```

Comment: that wont allow for a variable named `$task` in the view, unless that `$task` var is an array with a key named `task`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show($project_id,$task_id) { 

$project = Project::find($project_id); 
$task = Task::find($task_id); 

return view('task.show', ['task' => $task,'project' => $project]);

}
```

Comment: My show function is in TaskController, and My files/form.blade.php is include in task/show.blade.php

Comment: corrected "tasks.show" into "task.show" or if you want file/form.blade.php use view('file.form',....

Comment: did it but not sucess

Comment: Perhaps you try to explain what this code snippet does. Thus OP and future users can benefit from your help. Thanks.

Comment: @John: For understanding you are at view "files.form" and want to send file to FilesController ? And than output the 'task.show' view? Did you debug the uploadAttachments? is everything correct there? what is the output

Comment: files.form view is showing files attachments related to each tasks.